# Different imports according to version of dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a module that uses `Control.Exception` in `Base < 4` which is `Control.OldException` in `Base >= 4`. How can I, using cabal or any other tool, get rid of the version dependency (just depend on `Base` and not `Base < 4`) and import `Control.OldException` when using `Base >= 4` and `Control.Exception` when using `Base < 4`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cabal` [automatically sets certain CPP definitions](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html#cpp) based on the version of packages used.

So for your case I would:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module Blah where
#if MIN_VERSION_base(0,4,0)
import Control.OldException
#else
import Control.Exception
#endif
```

This method builds fine with cabal.

(actually, I would use new exceptions and wouldn't bother supporting base < 4, but that's just me)

Answer (score 1):

With Cabal this is done with "flags" and its constraint solving algorithm.  An example (from [control-monad-exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-exception) on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/)):

```
Flag extensibleExceptions
  description: Use extensible-exception package
  default: False

(...)

  if flag(extensibleExceptions)
    build-depends:
      extensible-exceptions >= 0.1 && <0.2,
      base >= 3.0 && <4
  else
    build-depends:
      base >= 4 && < 5
```

On a machine with an older version of `base`, Cabal will try to solve the dependency with `extensibleExceptions False`, fail, then retry with it `True` and use the different `build-depends`, which will succeed.  (You can also turn the flag on from the command line.)

http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html#configurations documents this mechanism, and the rest of the page describes other mechanisms including direct conditionals such as `if impl(ghc >= 6.10.0)`.

Comment: This is the solution for the opposite of what he's doing (for if he was using _new_ exceptions).  Since he's using the old exceptions (unfortunately) and `Control.OldException` is still in base (unfortunately) then he just needs to use CPP.  Unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

This is a language agnostic answer, so it may not apply for you.

There's a couple options

1. Wrap both exceptions in a SuperException that has both implementations. Give it a parameter that tells it what implementation to use based on `Base`.
2. Refactor Exception to be a child of OldException with overriden calls. (best option)

Comment: You are correct, this doesn't really apply here, this would require a refactoring of Haskells standard library. Something I am not in position to do =D. What you might not realize is that Control.Exception is not a class, it is a module.